# Remove the borders/control box from a WPF Form but still be able to move my form

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, forms

I have `WPF` application and after set `WindowStyle` to `None`, and `ResizeMode` to `NoResize` the border removed but now i cannot move my application with the mouse left button.
Any idea how to do that ?

After added this:

```
private void Window_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    this.DragMove();
}
```

My label event stop working

this is my label `MouseLeftButtonUp` event:

```
private void lblClose_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Close();
}
```

And now it's not even getting inside this method but i saw that `lblClose_MouseLeftButtonDown` do the job.

Why this is happening ?

Answer (score 0):

you  have to implement `MouseLeftButtonDown`  with  `DragMove` Method

```
 private void Window_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            this.DragMove();
        }
```

//window xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" ResizeMode="NoResize" MouseLeftButtonDown="Window_MouseLeftButtonDown" WindowStyle="None">
    <Grid>


    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Edit**

based on  your update the `MouseLeftButtonUp` will not working  when you use `DragMove()`  as it's synchronous method which  require a `WM_LBUTTONUP` native message to handle the window move  correctly which cancel the execution `MouseLeftButtonUp`

Comment: That is strange because its working but now all my button event doing nothing, even close button (close())

Comment: post some code of how you are doing it's the best way to help u

Comment: Please see my update (BTW i am using label events and not buttons)

Comment: unfortunately same results

Comment: what u mean by same result

Comment: My labels events still not responding to any event